# How send a file in email without saving file to disk?

Tags: email, attachment

I need to send a vcal file via email. I want to send the file without creating it on disk.
I have the file in string format.

Comment: Do you mean you want to send it without loading entirely into memory or what is your limitation?

Comment: I have file content in string formt, need to send it through mail without first save file in memory and then attach it with mail from memory

Comment: Do you mean not saving it onto a disk or what?

Comment: by 'memory', you probably mean "save to file" you can't avoid getting the file in memory (which usually refers to RAM).

Comment: it would also help if you specified what programming language/environment you're using. there are a lot of email libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think you are looking for in C#

```
 System.IO.StringReader stream = new System.IO.StringReader("xyz");
 Attachment attach = new Attachment(stream);
 MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
 msg.Attachments.Add(attach);
 SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
 client.Send(msg);
```

"xyz" should be replaced with the string of the attachment.  The code above will allow you to add an attachment to a MailMessage object without ever having to retrieve that object's data from disk, which is what I think you meant instead of 'memory'.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best you can do (if you're using a graphical email program) is just save the `.vcal` file to a temporary directory, then pass that path to the mail program.

You can generate temporary filenames with functions like [`mktemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktemp).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by not 'creating it memory'. Operating systems work by reading any file from disk into in-memory buffers. So, chances are that the file will still reside in memory at some point. Furthermore, when you pass the file over to the programme or tool that will dispatch it, it will also pass through some memory buffer.